# Geocoder not returning the value of the city

Tags: javascript, return-value, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have a function in my map.js file called getNameOfCity() (The function is below) It is called from my actions.js file by doing the following `var city = getNameOfCity();` I then alert city and it says undefined.

Here is the function in map.js

```
function getNameOfCity() {
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': map.getCenter()}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]){
                jQuery.each(results[0].address_components, function(key, value){
                    if(value.types[0] == 'locality') {
                        return value.long_name;
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

When I alert value.long_name just before I return the correct city is alerted. But when I alert city back from where the function was called it returns undefined. Any ideas on why?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to return value.long_name as the city? asking coz, i haven't worked with maps...but if you want to return that, i know where's the problem

Comment: the geocoder puts the name of the city in value.long_name. I want to return the result eg "London" back to the function so if I call the function like test = getNameOfCity(); test would contain the value "London"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Adam said, the problem is you are returning to the anonymous function. do this instead:

```
function getNameOfCity() {
    var city = '';
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': map.getCenter()}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]){
                jQuery.each(results[0].address_components, function(key, value){
                    if(value.types[0] == 'locality') {
                        city = value.long_name;
                    }
                });
                return city;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**
The callback way, as you were suggested...

```
function getNameOfCity(callback) {
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': map.getCenter()}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]){
                jQuery.each(results[0].address_components, function(key, value){
                    if(value.types[0] == 'locality') {
                        callback(value.long_name); // call the function, pass the city name.
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            callback(false); // not found? pass false instead.
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
You can now use this function to get the city name this way:

```
getNameOfCity(function(city) {
    alert(city);   // or do something less useless.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I have copied and pasted the code above, it still returns undefined.

Comment: Any other ideas? Looking around a lot of people suggest using a callback(city); How would I do this?

Comment: that's actually a great idea! wonder why i didn't think of it...look at the revised code...

Comment: If now gives an error in the console saying "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" (line callback(value.long_name);

Comment: that's because you have to pass a function to getNameOfCity that will be called and will be given the city name as it's first argument...sigh, i'll update the post again to give an example on how to use it....

Comment: Thanks, you are being a great help. It now alerts the city back but I want to use that result outside the function getNameOfCity eg. var test;
  getNameOfCity(function(city) {
      test = city; 
  });
  alert(test); test is declared outside the function so I should be able to use it outside the scope of the getNameOfCity function?

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a value inside an anonymous function - so you're returning it to nothing.

What you need to be doing is calling a function when your response is returned to say, "I'm done, here's the city name".

Comment: Ahhh, I see that now :-) How would I modify the function above to do so. Thanks for noticing